# select * that match user postcode in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display a list of users who live locally to the user who is logged in. so if the logged in session user has a postcode of 'm3 4' and 5 other users have a postcode beginning with 'm3 4' then these users will be shown to the user.

My table is laid out like this:

```
id  |   user_id  | user_postcode
1          2          M3 4
2          3          SM2 7
3          4          M3 4
```

so in this scenario user 2 will be shown to user 4 who is logged in because their post codes match.

I'm trying to do this in mysql and it works when i put the postcode in manually like so:

```
AND ptb_stats.user_postcode='M3 4'
```

but I'm trying to make it user session specific, so if the logged in user / $_SESSION[user_id'] has the same post code as other users.

i'm trying to do it this way, but it's showing all the users without postcodes where as it should be showing the users that have matching postcodes, shouldn't it?

```
function get_local_users() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "
            SELECT *
            From ptb_stats, ptb_users
            WHERE ptb_stats.user_id=ptb_users.id
            AND ptb_stats.user_postcode='".$_SESSION['user_postcode']."'";
            $local_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($local_set);
            return $local_set;
        }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What do you have inside `$_SESSION['user_postcode']` ? What does `confirm_query` do?

Comment: Also, please don't use `SELECT *`.  You should always know what fields you expect in the result.

Comment: I would do a `var_dump($_SESSION);` to check whether that key is actually set in the `$_SESSION` superglobal. Make sure also you have called `session_start();`. Plus, you don't need to declare `$_SESSION` as a global; it is always global.

Comment: @j0k it doesn't do anything, i thought session was a standard function and i could just add the column name user_postcode?

Comment: @JamesTanner not at all, you need to put some value inside.

Comment: @j0k ok I'm still learning, please can you tell me how i do this?

Comment: @JamesTanner did you already define `$_SESSION[user_id']` somewhere or not?

Comment: @j0k well my friend did it i think, it could be this:  function logged_in() {
  return isset($_SESSION['user_id']);
 }

Answer (score 0):

If the user id is stored in `$_SESSION['user_id']`, you can get the local users with

```
select u.id, u.name
from ptb_users u
join ptb_stats s1 on s1.user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']
join ptb_stats s2 on s2.user_id = u.id and s2.user_postcode = s1.user_postcode
where u.id <> $_SESSION['user_id']
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54d84/12/0)

If you have the postcode in `$_SESSION['user_postcode']`, it is even easier

```
select u.id, u.name
from ptb_users u
join ptb_stats s on s.user_id = u.id
     and s.user_postcode = $_SESSION['user_postcode']
where u.id <> $_SESSION['user_id']
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54d84/13/0)

Answer (score 0):

With this answer, I assume that the $_SESSION['user_postcode'] is filled from some type of input box and the value is a valid zipCode (like "M3 4").

You can use preg_match to split the zipcode from the number and try to select zipcodes form the db. Take a look at this example:

```
$matches = array();
$zipCode = preg_match('/^([a-z0-9]+)/i', $_SESSION['user_postcode'], $matches);
```

The zipcode is now in the $matches variable at the second place ($matches[1]).
Now use this value to create a query and check if it is the same as others..

```
$query = "SELECT *
        From ptb_stats, ptb_users
        WHERE ptb_stats.user_id=ptb_users.id
        AND ptb_stats.user_postcode REGEX '^" . $matches[1] . "'";
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't read the post very good, I assumed that the number after the space (in zipcode) was the housenumber. My bad :(.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you describe, I will go onto something like that.

I used prepared statement from PDO to handle the query.

```
function get_local_users() {
    // given that it was created like this: $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
    global $connection;

    $stmt = $connection->prepare(
        "SELECT ptb_stats.*
        FROM ptb_stats, ptb_users
        WHERE ptb_stats.user_id = ptb_users.id
        AND ptb_stats.user_id != ?
        AND ptb_stats.user_postcode = (
            SELECT user_postcode 
            FROM ptb_stats 
            WHERE user_id = ?
        )");

    $stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['user_id']));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $rows;
}
```