# how to set $_SESSION variable to use in sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im not sure if i've got this right but i could do with some help to point me in the right direction please.

basically i have a table called `ptb_stats`. this table lay out looks like this:

```
user_id  |  user_postcode

   1             m3 4
   2             m3 4
   3             kt1 3
   4             sm2 7
```

i am trying to generate a mysql query that will bring up all the users that have matching postcodes.
so for instance if `user 1 / user_id 1` is logged in then they will see `user 2` who has the same postcode as them (begining with m3 4)

this tells the user aproximately that user 1 and user 2 are within 5 miles of each other as an example.

i've got a working query which is this:

```
function get_local_users() {
            global $connection;
            $query = "
            SELECT *
            From ptb_stats, ptb_users
            WHERE ptb_stats.user_id=ptb_users.id
            AND ptb_stats.user_postcode='m3 4'
            AND ptb_users.id!=".$_SESSION['user_id']."";
            $local_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($local_set);
            return $local_set;  

        }
```

at the moment im having to enter the postcode manually into the query for it to work. my problem is that i need to assign a session variable i believe which will tell the query to match users with the same postcodes to the user who is logged in.

at the moment i have $_SESSION['user_id'] set as a variable but someone previously set this variable and i am trying to fix all their work but am unable to get in touch with the guy who did it. So i don't understand session variables. i thought i could just change $_SESSION['user_id'] to $_SESSION['user_postcode'] and it would work, but basically what i need to do is some how get the query to say:

if the logged in user's `user_postcode` is (whatever value) and their are other users with matching `user_postcodes` then display these.

can someone please show me what i would need to do to get this to work. i would really appreciate it. thank you.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I suggest, you look at the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/15338359/1741542

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM
        tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_postcode
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY user_postcode
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON a.user_postcode = b.user_postcode
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45e1a/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with filter*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45e1a/2)

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
function get_local_users() 
{ 
    global $connection; 
    $query = "  SELECT  a.* 
                FROM    ptb_stats a 
                        INNER JOIN 
                        ( 
                            SELECT user_postcode 
                            FROM ptb_stats 
                            GROUP BY user_postcode 
                            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id  ) > 1 
                        ) b ON a.user_postcode = b.user_postcode 
                WHERE a.user_id <> " . $_SESSION['user_id']; 
    $local_set = mysql_query($query, $connection); 
    confirm_query($local_set); 
    return $local_set; 
}
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: but how does this filter out the results to the logged in user?

Comment: i tried with the filter and i get a mysql error:   function get_local_users() {
   global $connection;
   $query = "
   SET @sessionID = ".$_SESSION['user_id'].";

SELECT  a.*
FROM
        ptb_stats a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_postcode
            FROM    ptb_stats
            GROUP   BY user_postcode
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON a.user_postcode = b.user_postcode
WHERE   a.user_id <> @sessionID;
 
      ";
   $local_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
   confirm_query($local_set);
   return $local_set;
   
   
  }

Comment: this is the error im getting:  Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT a.* FROM ptb_stats a INNER JOIN ( SE' at line 3

Comment: I tried your updated answer, thansk for this, but it brings up all users, it doesn't select only those with matching postcodes?

Comment: it is the postcode the return from the subquery and which it has multiple `user_id`.

Comment: ok, is there a way i can get it to only show those users who have matching user_postcodes as the session user?